# How to handle a session timeout exception (with MVP Places and Activities)?

Tags: session, gwt, mvp

how do you handle a time out request in a GWT app ?
Here is a snipped of my web.xml file :

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

My GWT project is based on MVP Activities and Places.
Whenever the user waits more than 30mn, i want to display a popup and redirect the user to the login page. Here is what i do for
all RPC services :

```
 public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    ...
    if (caught instanceof InvocationException) {
                    {
                        Window.alert("Time out de session. Veuillez vous reconnecter. 2");
                        Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "identification.html", "_self", null);
                        return;
                    }
    ...}
```

It works but several things are annoying :
1) the caught exception should be RequestTimeoutException. But it's not caught, which is why i use InvocationException instead.
How come it's not caught ?
2) how can i handle this exception in a more generic way ? It's a bit stupid to have to catch that exception in all RPC services ...
I read about some AsyncCallbackAdapter class ...
3) Right now i handle RPC services only but of course time out exception occurs everywhere : links, buttons, page refresh ...
I'm using MVP Places and Activities.
Is there a way to catch that exception when the user tries to go to a place ?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

1. [`RequestTimeoutException`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestTimeoutException.html) is thrown when server is not responding.
2. You should create you own checked exception, something like `SessionTimeoutException` and handle it in you client code. GWT knows how to handle (serialize) checked exceptions and pass them to your client code: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#exceptions

   To handle this in application-wide way, you can hook into RPC mechanism, by creating you own generator for remote services: [How to redirect to login page after session expire in GWT RPC call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657572/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-after-session-expire-in-gwt-rpc-call/3672122#3672122)
3. The easiest way (without changing all existing code) would be to set a [`Timer`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) to periodically check (every few minutes) the server session. When session times out show a modal `DialogBox` (preventing user input on other widgets) notifying user he/she needs to login again.