# JSNI - $wnd.location.assign() not triggering immediately

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, xmlhttprequest, jsni

I have the following JSNI code in my GWT app that makes an HTTP request to detect a URL redirect -

```
private native void checkSession(String url)
    /*-{
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (url != xhr.responseURL) {
                        $wnd.alert("Your session has timed out.");
                        $wnd.location.assign(url);
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.send();
    }-*/;
```

If the URL requested is not the same as the response URL, the session is deemed to be timed out; upon which I want to display an alert box letting the user know that the session has timed out, and initiate a redirect when they click on OK.

I have a custom class that implements `AsyncCallback`. Using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672122/3906773), I was able to globally enforce `onFailure()` to call `checkSession()` whenever a `StatusCodeException` occurs.

The problem is that the alert box pops up several times before `$wnd.location.assign(url)` can initiate the redirect. I realize that several `onFailure()` methods are being executed here causing the alert to pop up several times, but my question is, why is `$wnd.location.assign(url)` not being executed until the last `onFailure()` method is executed, while `$wnd.alert()` which is right above it, being executed every single time?

How can I force a redirect in this situation? Ideally, I want the alert to pop up once, and redirect immediately upon OK being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525646/3906773), the browser will try to execute the remaining JavaScript code until the page is redirected; which explains the occurrence of multiple alerts before the page redirects.

To get around this, I declared `private static boolean redirect = false;`.
When a URL redirect is detected within the JSNI code, I check if `redirect` is `false`, and if it is, I display the alert and set `redirect = true` -

```
if (@fully.qualified.name::redirect == false) {
       @fully.qualified.name::redirect = true;
       $wnd.alert("Your session has timed out.");
}
$wnd.location.assign(url);
```

That way, I was able to show the alert only once before initiating a redirect.